# What's wrong with my xsdata Python code? (ParserError Unknown property)

Tags: python, xml

Does anyone see the problem why I get the following exception

> Exception has occurred: ParserError Unknown property MyConnection:NodeName

in this **xsdata** sample code?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List
from xsdata.formats.dataclass.parsers import XmlParser
from xsdata.formats.dataclass.parsers.config import ParserConfig

xml = """
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <LineList>
        <Line>
            <ConnectionList>
                <Connection>
                    <NodeName>ABC</NodeName>
                </Connection>
                <Connection>
                    <NodeName>DEF</NodeName>
                </Connection>
            </ConnectionList>
        </Line>
    </LineList>
  """


@dataclass
class MyConnection:
    node_name: str = field(metadata=dict(name="NodeName"))

@dataclass
class MyConnectionList:
    connections: List[MyConnection] = field(default_factory=list, metadata=dict(name="Connection"))

@dataclass
class MyLine:
    connection_list: MyConnectionList = field(metadata=dict(name="ConnectionList"))

@dataclass
class MyLineList:
    class Meta:
        name = "LineList"
    lines: List[MyLine] = field(default_factory=list, metadata=dict(name="Line"))

config = ParserConfig(fail_on_unknown_properties=True)
parser = XmlParser(config=config)
obj = parser.from_string(xml, MyLineList)
```

I have no idea what's going wrong!

Regards,
Daniel.

Comment: what is `xsdata` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your MyConnection.node_name field to include the [xml type](https://xsdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#field-metadata), the model context assumes that your field is a a text value node, because the class has just **one** primitive field. It's better to be explicit.

```
@dataclass
class MyConnection:
    node_name: str = field(metadata=dict(name="NodeName", type="Element"))
```

Also xsdata ships with a code generator that you can use for mapping xml samples to models as well or at least get you started

- xsdata generate sample.xml
- xsdata generate samples_dir/

Given your sample it will generate the following for you

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List, Optional


@dataclass
class Connection:
    node_name: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={
            "name": "NodeName",
            "type": "Element",
        }
    )


@dataclass
class ConnectionList:
    connection: List[Connection] = field(
        default_factory=list,
        metadata={
            "name": "Connection",
            "type": "Element",
        }
    )


@dataclass
class Line:
    connection_list: Optional[ConnectionList] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={
            "name": "ConnectionList",
            "type": "Element",
        }
    )


@dataclass
class LineList:
    line: Optional[Line] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={
            "name": "Line",
            "type": "Element",
        }
    )
```